# Define an order for ManyToManyField by through model field with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

```
class ProductRelation(models.Model):
    product_a = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    product_a_rank = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Position')
    product_b = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    product_b_rank = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Postition')

class Product(models.Model):
    b_products = models.ManyToManyField('self', through=ProductRelation, symmetrical=False,
    through_fields=('product_a', 'product_b'),
    related_name='a_products',
    )
```

Hello. I have `product` Product instance. How can I get those ordered results?
`product.b_products.all().order_by('product_b_rank')`
and
`product.a_products.all().order_by('product_a_rank')`

Django 1.8

Answer (score 2):

Use a **double underscore** to `order_by` a related field:

```
Product.objects.order_by("b_products__product_b_rank")
```

Edit:

```
product.product_a.order_by('product_b_rank')
product.product_b.order_by('product_a_rank')
```

Comment: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'product_b_rank' into field. `

Comment: The best aproximation for now is:  
`[relation.product_b for relation in product.product_a_set.order_by('product_b_rank')]`